# Computing covariance matrix with historical data

Tags: risk, covariance, covariance-matrix, correlation-matrix

I have been reading Active Portfolio Management by Grinold and Khan. In the chapter about risk, they mention,

*"The third elementary model relies on historical variances and covariances. This procedure is neither robust nor reasonable. Historical models rely on data from T periods to estimate the $NxN$ covariance matrix. If T is less than or equal to N, we can find active positions that will appear riskless! So the historical approach requires $T > N$. For a monthly historical covariance matrix of S&P 500 stocks, this would require more than 40 years of data."*

When forming mean-variance optimal portfolio, we would need to invert the covariance matrix hence, we require a full rank covariance matrix. In this case using historical returns is not robust.

However, if the main intention is to compute an estimate of the variance of the portfolio $w'\Sigma w$ where $w$ is the weight or holdings of stock, in such a use case, we can estimate $\Sigma$ with $T<N$ right? As we are not inverting the covariance matrix, the concern of not full rank is less of an issue, right?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t see how just calculation of Portfolio variance would need an invertible var-covar matrix, I mean you don’t even have to use the matrix notation to calculate it.  It may be so that lower time frames would output unstable values of the individual variances and pairwise correlations.

However there are certain methods to achieve a stable covariance matrix in such cases like shrinkage estimation. You’d always be better off using such methods, the above paragraph just comments on the theoretical possibility of such a matrix.

Comment: I don't see how you can estimate $\Sigma$ with $T < N $. Can you explain that ? You have an $N$ by $N$ matrix, $\Sigma$, and $T$ periods of data so it's not possible as far as I can tell.

Comment: You can simply calculate Variance for each asset for the T period, and the pairwise correlations for each pair separately for the same period, then plug all the values in the matrix, it’s definitely possible, but it won’t be stable for small T, as I wrote above.

Comment: I think it's more difficult than that because if they say $T < N$ means that positions will appear riskless, they mean that your covariance matrix is going to have elements that are zero. So, although I'm not clear on why, I'd be careful because those two guys know what they're talking about. It may have something to do with the estimation of the covariance matrix being more complex than plugging in estimated correlations.  ( maybe a risk model ? ).  If you think you're way is okay, go for it. Or maybe look closer at the book to see what they mean by that statement.

Comment: It may have something to do with independence. If stock X has T observations of returns, you probably don't want to use the same T observations for estimation of the correlations of X with the other N-1 stocks. If you do that, you'll probably end up with a matrix that's not positive definite because the resulting estimates won't be independent because of $T$ < $N$.   I'm no whiz at covariance matrix estimation but it probably has something do with the rank of the resulting estimated matrix not being N.

Comment: In the Wikipedia article for shrinkage estimation it says “ If the sample size n is small and the number of considered variables p is large, the above empirical estimators of covariance and correlation are very unstable”. As I said it will be unstable, but OP was asking if it was “theoretically” possible or not, it is. But It’s always better to use certain techniques in case of low observations, I’ll add that to answer to be safe for future readers.

Comment: I do not believe it has something to do with independence, I think the main concern would be 1) Usage, non invertible covariance matrixes would be unsuitable for use in many methods from Linear regression to Portfolio optimisation. 

2) The Eigenvalues would be spread out and the consistency might become a problems

Comment: If $T<N$ the resulting sample covariance matrix will have $N-T$ eigenvalues that are identical to zero (theoretically). This makes the matrix non-invertible and non-positive definite (but semi-definite), which can cause problems for ex. in matrix inversion. But furthermore those 0 eigenvalues can easily become slightly negative in practice due to roundoff error and this causes further problems in computer applications (even semi-definiteness fails).

Comment: @noob2: thanks for clarification. I knew it had something to do with that but your pinpointed details are quite clear and appreciated.

Comment: @noob2: is there some text or notes that go into what you said ( the first part about the eigenvalues and the non-positive definiteness etc ) in even more detail.  I'm just curious because I get the idea but I  can't "see that" as obvious by any stretch. thanks.

Comment: You can get zero eigenvalues, e.g. because some market factors are linear combinations of ohers, e.g. some currency is pegged to another or basket of currencies; or an equity index and all of its components. One common reason for getting negative eigenvalues is missing historical data. E.g. you have 3 years of data for some A and B, so you use them for the covariance of A and B; but you only have 1 year for some C, so you can only use 1 year for the covariances of A and C and B and C. Numerically, you could "fudge" the matrix to have no eigenvalues less than, say, 2% of its largest one.

Comment: @Dimitri Vulis: Thanks. That was  interesting  but, if it was to me, then I meant a reference for the mathematics behind T < N causing some eigenvalues of the estimated covariance matrix to be zero. As the OP said, you can calculate correlations and use them for estimates of the individual elements so it's not obvious to me why the resulting matrix is not full rank. I mean, intuitively it is but not mathematically.  I found some notes on the net but nothing great yet. I figured noob2 might know since he formalized the concept that I was thinking was true.

Comment: @noob2 : According to MIT eigenvalues would spread out, Larger the N/T ( or p/n ). “But when p is large (larger than n, or depend on n), this estimator could be very bad. If p/n → c ∈ (0,1) and the covariance matrix Σ(p)= I, then the empirical distribution of the eigenvalues of Σ(p) is supported on ((1 − sqrt(c))^2 , (1 + sqrt(c))^2 ). Thus the larger p/n, the more
spread out the eigenvalues. This means in terms of ∥ · ∥2 norm, Σp is not consistent.”

Comment: Link to doc : http://math.mit.edu/~liewang/ECM.pdf

Comment: Dhruv: I think you mean to write that to me ? Nice document. The important statement in your document ( top of page 2 ) is that one is estimating $N$ by $N$ params with $T$ by $N$ observations. That's the key reason (atleast to me) why  $T$ < $N$ is a problem. You're  original idea to estimate  the corrs one by one and then plug them into the matrix won't work ( and is not used in general in the literature )  because it won't guarantee  linear independence.  One needs to A) estimate the matrix "simultaneously" and B) $T$ > $N$ in order to guarantee full rank of the resulting matrix.

Comment: Dhruv:  I mentioned that your plug-in approach won't guarantee linear independence of the columns. This is true but besides not guaranteeing linear independence, the other reason one needs to estimate the matrix simultaneously  is because one desires consistency of the matrix estimate. Doing it your way, where you do each element one by one doesn't guarantee consistency because one is considering each element individually rather than the properties of the matrix as whole. A little hand waving there but hopefully you can "see" why your suggestion is not used.